# Laravel ErrorException(code: 0): Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, json, laravel, guzzle, laravel-6

I am using Guzzle in my laravel version 6.x application to call an external endpoint. Then I am trying to access the response attributes if the response status is 200 with this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function createdDedicatedAccount()
    {
        $client = new Client(['verify' => false]);

        $secretKey = 'some_secret_key';
        $url = 'target_url';
        $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $secretKey,
            'content-type'  => 'application/json',
        ];

        Log::info('Requesting dedicated account assignment to customer: ' . 24101696);

        $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'headers' => $headers,
            'json' => ['customer' => 24101696]
        ]);

        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            Log::info('Dedicated account assigned.');

            $dedicatedAccount = json_decode($response->getBody());
            Log::info('dedicatedAccount: ' . $dedicatedAccount);
            Log::info('account_number: ' . $dedicatedAccount->data->account_number);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to access the attribute, I get this exception error

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Here's what's logged

```
[2020-05-14 13:01:17] local.INFO: Customer created successfully with id: 24101696  
[2020-05-14 13:01:17] local.INFO: Requesting dedicated account assignment to customer: 24101696  
[2020-05-14 13:01:18] local.INFO: Dedicated account assigned.  
[2020-05-14 13:01:18] local.ERROR: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

If I do not `json_decode` the `response->getBody()`, I am able to successfully log the `dedicatedAccount` like this

```
[2020-05-14 13:47:35] local.INFO: Customer created successfully on with id: 24103237  
[2020-05-14 13:47:35] local.INFO: Requesting dedicated account assignment to customer: 24103237  
[2020-05-14 13:47:37] local.INFO: Dedicated account assigned.  
[2020-05-14 13:47:37] local.INFO: dedicated_account: {
  "status": true,
  "message": "Account successfully created",
  "data": {
    "bank": {
      "name": "Test Bank",
      "id": 25,
      "slug": "test-bank"
    },
    "account_name": "TEST TEST",
    "account_number": "9930892996",
    "assigned": true,
    "currency": "NGN",
    "metadata": null,
    "active": true,
    "id": 89505,
    "created_at": "2020-03-30T10:13:13.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-14T12:47:38.000Z",
    "assignment": {
      "integration": 103612,
      "assignee_id": 24103237,
      "assignee_type": "Customer",
      "expired": false,
      "account_type": "PAY-WITH-TRANSFER-RECURRING",
      "assigned_at": "2020-05-14T12:47:38.588Z",
      "expired_at": null
    },
    "customer": {
      "id": 24103237,
      "first_name": "Test",
      "last_name": "Test",
      "email": "5_test@test.co",
      "customer_code": "CUS_ofuz99njymux0g9",
      "phone": null,
      "metadata": null,
      "risk_action": "default"
    }
  }
}  
[2020-05-14 13:47:37] local.ERROR: Undefined property: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::$data
```

But still end up with another exception error message.

What is the right way to handle the response I am getting so that I can access the attributes of the object?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is in the following lines of code:

```
if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
    Log::info('Dedicated account assigned.');

    $dedicatedAccount = json_decode($response->getBody());
    Log::info('dedicatedAccount: ' . $dedicatedAccount);
    Log::info('account_number: ' . $dedicatedAccount->data->account_number);
}
```

For a quick fix, remove the line `Log::info('dedicatedAccount: ' . $dedicatedAccount);` and try running your code. Lemme explain. Once you decode your response body, it becomes an object with the properties that have been sent from the API. This object cannot be logged since the Log::info function expects a string and not an object. If you really want to see the object, then log it as a json encoded string thus changing the above code to:

```
if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
    Log::info('Dedicated account assigned.');

    $dedicatedAccount = json_decode($response->getBody());
    Log::info('dedicatedAccount: ' . json_encode($dedicatedAccount));
    Log::info('account_number: ' . $dedicatedAccount->data->account_number);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course I will be able to see the data but I still can't access the attributes which I want I want to achieve. So if I set the variable like this `$dedicatedAccount = json_encode(json_decode($response->getBody()));` I will be able to log the `$dedicatedAccount` but won't be able log `$dedicatedAccount->data->account_number`. It throws the error `Trying to get property 'data' of non-object` which means it still doesn't know about the object returned.

Comment: If you check my answer up there, i am logging `json_encode($dedicatedAccount)` but my `$dedicatedAccount = json_decode($response->getBody())`. So i am logging a string but my `$dedicatedAccount` remains an object since it was already decoded. From the code you posted in the question the only thing i have done is change `Log::info('dedicatedAccount: ' . $dedicatedAccount);` to `Log::info('dedicatedAccount: ' . json_encode($dedicatedAccount));`

Comment: I get you. So how would I do it if I want to return the `$dedicatedAccount` and access the attributes by doing something like `$dedicatedAccount->data->account_number`? The reason I am logging it is to check if actually I am getting the object in the first place.

Comment: First, remove the `Log:info` statements. Then, if you would only like that specific property of the object, just return it as is `return $dedicatedAccount->data->account_number`. Otherwise, return the whole object like `return $dedicatedAccount`. Then if your `$response->getStatusCode()` is not 200, you can `return false` or `return null` depending on preference.